# CKEDITOR.replace() will grey out my text in textarea as well as items in toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to use `CKEDITOR.replace('mytextarea')` but when my page loads it will grey out my text in textarea (so it seems to be blank) as well as items in toolbar are greyed out so I can't to modify it.

Why this happens and how to do it correctly?

Comment: Have you add CSS files on your project ?

Comment: Yes, I did it. But no luck...

Answer (score 1):

I found problem! There must be something wrong with ckeditor files. I downloaded new package and now it is working.